# Seurat, interfering with ggplot2/plotly output

Tags: r, ggplot2, package, seurat

I am writing an R script in Rstudio looking at single cell data and generating various graphs. The package I am using is ggplot2. It generates nice graph outputs like this when the Seurat library is not loaded:  [image: Pure ggplot2 graph]

Then when the Seurat library is imported, the graph reverts to this ugliness: [image: Seurat Interfered Plot]
Here is a list of the imports that Seurat brings upon being included:

```
Imports: methods, ROCR, stringr, mixtools, lars, fastICA, tsne, Rtsne,
        fpc, ape, VGAM, pbapply, igraph, FNN, caret, plyr, dplyr,
        RColorBrewer, MASS, Matrix, irlba, reshape2, gridExtra, gplots,
        gdata, Rcpp, RcppEigen, RcppProgress, tclust, ranger
```

Any thoughts on how to have both libraries present without the alterations in the graph output?

Solutions Tried:

- tried "detach("package:Seurat", unload = TRUE)" //did not revert plots upon closing and reloading RStudio AND did not allow for upstream code chunks to provide ggplot2 normal graphing.

Comment: It looks like Seurat must change the default theme settings. Try your plot code `+ theme_gray()` and see if that reverts it to the pre-Seurat settings.

Comment: Seems to work, thank you very much ! @Brian

Comment: @Brian please post as answer.

Comment: @zx8754 I did, and hopefully it was a more interesting answer than my brief comment.

Answer (score 1):

A comment asked me to post my fix as an answer, so I did a little digging. When unexpected behavior happens after you call `library(package)`, that's because that package has a function called `.onLoad` or `.onAttach`. These are automatically run upon loading or attaching the package, and are usually used to set options, print helpful messages, etc. Best practices say you should undo any actions with a complement function, `.onUnload`. See: https://r-pkgs.org/r.html#when-you-do-need-side-effects

> Occasionally, packages do need side-effects. This is most common if
>   your package talks to an external system — you might need to do some
>   initial setup when the package loads. ... If you use .onLoad(),
>   consider using .onUnload() to clean up any side effects. By
>   convention, .onLoad() and friends are usually saved in a file called
>   zzz.R.

So I went looking in the Github repo for the package `Seurat`, and didn't see any `ggplot2`-related options (https://github.com/satijalab/seurat/blob/master/R/zzz.R). Next up was to check that package's `DESCRIPTION`, which shows me the packages that are loaded that `Seurat` uses. It's a long list, but I recognized a somewhat common custom graphics package on there, `cowplot`. If you then go to that repo (https://github.com/wilkelab/cowplot/blob/master/R/setup.R):

> ```
> .onAttach <- function(libname, pkgname) {
>   # switch the default theme to theme_cowplot
>   # ggplot2::theme_set(theme_cowplot())
>   packageStartupMessage("\n********************************************************")
>   packageStartupMessage("Note: As of version 1.0.0, cowplot does not change the")
>   packageStartupMessage("  default ggplot2 theme anymore. To recover the previous")
>   packageStartupMessage("  behavior, execute:\n  theme_set(theme_cowplot())")
>   packageStartupMessage("********************************************************\n")
> }
> ```

From these messages, you can see it **used to** be the case that loading `cowplot` changed the default theme for `ggplot2`. Out of curiosity I looked at the commits to see when this change happened at the source (although not when it was pushed to CRAN):

https://github.com/wilkelab/cowplot/commit/158ccdfa45d6c3e99c8568afaa73f7d68cd6c9c2#diff-c9a33000e506e95bca8089aa91efd8b2

> clauswilke committed on Mar 29, 2018

So, this question is no longer reproducible, as of roughly a year ago. However, this hunting process may still be useful to future readers when unexpected behavior occurs.

---

#### TL;DR:

`ggplot2`-specific fix: The original default theme is `theme_gray()`, so you can always manually add that to affected plots to revert to the previous behavior, if you can't isolate the package affecting your code.